# Write a non-trivial element of $ H^2 (\mathbb{C}P^2 \backslash \{ x = 0 \})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

I am trying to understand a bit of the homology of a projective space minus a hyperplane.

$$ \mathbb{C}P^2 \backslash \{ x = 0\} = \big\{ [x:y:z]: x \neq 0\big\} / \mathbb{C}^\times $$

This is topological space and therefore we can ask about finding non-trivial 2-cycles in this space.

One can ask more generally about the topology of projective spaces with hyperplanes removed.  If you remove a hyperplane from $\mathbb{R}^3$ the space $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{ x = 0\}$ is no longer connected.  However, there is a non-trivial 1-cycle in Euclidean 4-space with a single hyperplane removed  $S_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4 \backslash \{ x =y= 0\}$ :

$$ \big[ \big\{ ( \cos \theta,\sin \theta,0,0) : \theta \in [0,2\pi]  \big\} \big]  \in H_1 \big( \mathbb{R}^4 \backslash \{ x=y=0 \} \big) $$

Complex projective space is also a 4-manifold, since it's the quotient of $\big(\mathbb{C}^3 \backslash \{0\} \big) / \mathbb{C}^\times$ the dimension is $6 - 2 = 4$ (or complex dimension $3 - 1 = 2$.  I guess the confusing part is that:

$$  \mathbb{C}^3 \backslash \{ x = 0\} \text{ is connected} $$

Back to my original space, I am looking for non-trivial loops in $\mathbb{C}P^2 \backslash \{ x = 0\}$ that are not already in $\mathbb{C}P^2$.  We have for [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space#Homology):

$$ [hyperplane] \in H_2(\mathbb{C}P^2, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z} $$

My question is how the topology *changes* upon removing this hyperplane.  I  am flipping through Hatcher's [Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) textbook, which says in Chapter 2 that Homology behaves nicely under excision.   However, the nature of my question is elementary.

Perhaps I can phrase it this way... what are the generators of the homology of projective space minus a hyperplane:

$$ H^2 \big( \mathbb{C}P^2 \backslash \{ x = 0\}\big)$$

I'm not just looking for the homology group, but the topological subspaces that generate them.

Comment: When you say "non-trivial loops in $\mathbb{C}P^2 \smallsetminus \{x = 0\}$ that are not already in $\mathbb{C}P^2$", you have described the empty set.  All such loops in the difference set are loops in the full set through the inclusion injection.  Perhaps you mean "... that are trivial in $\mathbb{C}P^2$"?

Comment: @EricTowers The 1-cycle is in $\mathbb{R}^4 \backslash \{ (0,0) \times \mathbb{R}^2 \}$ that is (hopefully) 4-space with a hyperplane removed.

Comment: @EricTowers The space $\mathbb{C}P^2 \backslash \{ x = 0\}$ is hard to visualize, so I started with the easier 4-space minus a hyperplane: $\mathbb{R}^4 \backslash \{ x = y = 0\} $ or $ \mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{ x = 0\}$.  These are also hard to visualize.

Answer (score 3):

The map
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{C}P^2\backslash\{x=0\}&\to\mathbb{C}^2,\\
[x:y:z]&\mapsto \left(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
is a homeomorphism. This means the (co)homology groups of $\mathbb{C}P^2\backslash\{x=0\}$ are the same as those of $\mathbb{C}^2$, so in particular $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2\backslash\{x=0\})$ is trivial.

Comment: Wait... $H_2 (\mathbb{C}P^2) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.  Then I removed a hyperplane and got $H_2 (\mathbb{C}P^2 \backslash \{ x = 0\} ) \simeq \{0\}$ ?

Comment: @cactus314 : Yes.  The same thing happens to $\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus \{\Re(z) = 0\}$.  Every object in class $[1]$ (where $[1]$ generates $H_1$in this example and generated $H_2$ in the Question) is disconnected by the set deletion.

Comment: @cactus314 : That example got mangled through edits.  Start with $\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus \{0\}$.  This has $H_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Then delete the subspace $\Re(z) = 0$.  This space is disconnected, so does not have an unambiguous definition of $\pi_1$.  Nevertheless, every $1$- cycle in the path class generating the original $H_1$ is separated in the new space.  Each half of the surviving space is contractible.  The resulting $H_1$ is trivial.